# Installing and edit Javascript for Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This JS script work in *jsfidle*, but when I installing to *WP* it does not work.
I don't know what to change.

**Here is the code:**

```js
function roundNumber($number, decimals) {
    var newnumber = new Number($number+'').toFixed(parseInt(decimals));
    return parseFloat(newnumber); 
}
function add(){
    $result = (+$("#rate").val())*(+$("#quantity").val());
    $("#result").val(roundNumber($result, 12));
}
add();
$("input").blur(add);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="rate" name="rate" type="number" value="0"><br />
Amount: <span class="input-group-addon"></span><br />
<input type="number" id="quantity" step="0.001" min="0" max="0"  name="quantity" value="0"><br />
<input id="result" name="result" disabled value="0" >
```

Thank you for answer.

Comment: First step is opening your browser console and checking for errors.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Yes there is an error in console "Uncaught ReferenceError: roundNumber is not defined
    at (index):652"

Comment: I need an simple converter to calculate between price and quantity

Comment: Now you found the error you could investigate the call-stack.

Comment: I was removing the error code, but still not work for WP

Comment: code still not work for WordPress, can someone help